# SP2013: Empty "Crawl Load" in Crawl Health Reports

Tags: search

In a SharePoint Server 2013 farm, I am trying to investigate some performance issues with the Search service. When I navigate to the Crawl Health Reports to view the Crawl Load report, it is empty. The Crawl Latency report below it has information, but not Crawl Load. Any thoughts as to why?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Aside from the reports, what performance issues are you having?

Comment: We are seeing Crawls targeting a specific Web App (as a Content Source) taking much longer than expected, and sometimes going for days. Additionally, the web front end servers' app pool process for that Web Application consumes 5-6 GB of RAM and is causing the Web App to fail and not serve content. I want to note that this Web App contains a site collection that has a Document Library with ~25k items with unique permissions on each. We are suspicious that is the problem, but looking to quantify.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. Unique Permission can bog down the crawler as it enumerates the content and tracks the ACLs. There are boundaries and Limits to the number of unique permissions that you should use as a guideline.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Matthew! Appreciated your SPC14 session on customizing search as well. :)